# show the text within the "quotes" within a text input

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I'm making a query to the database and am showing the value in input type text as follows:

```
<input type='text' name='title' value="<?php echo  $noticia->_title; ?>" />
```

What happens is that if the text coming from the database comes within "" the text does not appear because the " " of value. If I switch to '' have the same problem if the text coming from the database is inside ''. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($noticia->_title) ?>"
```

htmlspecialchars() will encode any HTML metacharcters in there that would otherwise break your form, e.g.

```
$title = 'Hello "Joe"';

<input ... value="Hello "Joe"" />
                        ^---breaks the form
```

becomes

```
$title = htmlspecialchars('Hello "Joe"');
<input ... value="Hello &quot;Joe&quot;" />
```

Comment: Htmlspecialchars thought that did not apply in these situations. resulted! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Convert text to HTML with [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

```
echo htmlspecialchars($noticia->_title);
```

Comment: Htmlspecialchars thought that did not apply in these situations. resulted! thank you!